# Custom attrs and inheritance

Tags: android, android-attributes

I have a parent style

```
<style name="AppTheme">
    <item name="ColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    <item name="ColorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="fabEnabled">false</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.MyFragment" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="fabEnabled">true<item>
</style>

<attr name="fabEnabled" format="boolean"/>
```

And when I get my attributes in an Activity, with 
`obtainstyledattributes(attrs, R.style.AppTheme_MyFragment)`

colorPrimary is #FFFFFF 
But fabEnabled is false

Did I missed something ?

Thank you

Comment: Do I need do add something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to wrap the attributes with a use-stylable